# Vue transition layouts not triggering transition

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-transitions

I'm using [vite-plugin-vue-layouts](https://github.com/JohnCampionJr/vite-plugin-vue-layouts) pattern for my Vue3 project. I've been trying to follow docs to setup transitions between pages and I'm not able to make it work somehow... Pages are displaying pages but there is no transition between them...

**This is my layout page (admin-dashboard.vue)**

```
<style>
.v-enter-active,
.v-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.v-enter-from,
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<template>
  <Navigation />
  <main class="py-10 lg:pl-72">
    <div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <router-view v-slot="{ Component, route }">
        <transition>
          <div><component :is="Component" :key="route" /></div>
        </transition>
      </router-view>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
```

**and this is my page example (pages/admin/users/index.vue)**

```
<template>
  <Suspense>
    <template #default>
      <UsersTable />
    </template>

    <template #fallback>
      <LoadingSpinner />
    </template>
  </Suspense>
</template>
<script setup>
import LoadingSpinner from "~/components/LoadingSpinner.vue";
import UsersTable from "../../../components/admin/users/UsersTable.vue";
</script>
<route lang="yaml">
meta:
  layout: admin-dashboard
</route>
```

Comment: i think the problem is the `div` inside transition.. try to remove the `div`. your code should like this `<transition><component :is="Component" :key="route" /></transition>`

Comment: yep you are right! Do you maybe know a clean way to animate between different layouts as well? In my case I have a few different layouts which fetches data depending on the user role...

Comment: you can do it at the same way, `transition` triggered by `v-if` `v-show` `dynamic component` and `key`

Comment: I've tried but since I'm loading different promises for each of the layout a flicker (flashed white screen - even though I'm using suspense in App.vue) happens between them and between the animation...